# Restangular: Not passing parameter if empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, restangular

I have the following controller method in a AngularJS application using RestAngular:

```
    $scope.findFriend = function (name, type, limit) {
        return FriendSearch.getList({
            name: name,
            type: type,
            limit: limit
        });
    };
```

It might be that the **type** is **empty** (a string with no content, length = 0) - Restangular generates the following invalid URL:

```
http://host:port/rest/friends/search?limit=10&name=Peter&type=
```

Correct would be to omit it like:

```
http://host:port/rest/friends/search?limit=10&name=Peter
```

Of course, I can check the parameters before passing. But I would like to know if there is a nicer way to do that.

Comment: I think this might help you http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/restangular.html 'Using requestInterceptors'. From the doc 'We can work with the data we are going to send to the server' so you can go over the object and remove empty fields

Comment: @yuyokk Unfortunately, it is not working. There is no element present and the url is given without parameters as far as I could see.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this issue with Restangular version 1.4. I have created a fiddle resembling your example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ovwd8wUhBkhPXtBNDfbw?p=preview

Excerpt:

```
  // http://run.plnkr.co/search?name=foo
  $scope.findFriend('foo');
  // http://run.plnkr.co/search?name=foo&type=bar
  $scope.findFriend('foo', 'bar');
  // http://run.plnkr.co/search?limit=3&name=foo
  $scope.findFriend('foo', null, '3');
    // http://run.plnkr.co/search?limit=3&name=foo
  $scope.findFriend('foo', undefined, '3');
```

Both `null` and `undefined` given as parameters work as intended.
This means we need some more information / code because the behaviour might be caused by something else.

For the case of empty strings the most concise and easy way is to simply check for `''` and replace with null.

I updated the fiddle accordingly:

```
  $scope.findFriend = function (name, type, limit) {
    return FriendSearch.getList({
      name: name === '' ? null : name,
      type: type === '' ? null : type,
      limit: limit === '' ? null : limit
    });
  };
  // http://run.plnkr.co/search?limit=3&name=foo
  $scope.findFriend('foo', '', '3');
```

Comment: Thank you for your review. The version we use is the same. What I meant with empty in my description means an empty string. I will update the description to clarify this.